# Loose searching, e.g. such that "htlm" would find "html5"

Tags: html, mysql, sql, search, where-clause

I have a huge database with keywords such as `html`, `html5`, `xhtml`, and so on.
The user can search for rooms and as of now it is merely just implemented as

```
[...] WHERE name LIKE '%keyword%' LIMIT 20;
```

This is a simple solution to start with, but it is not fault-tolerant. And users make a lot of faults. To enhance this, I would like to introduce a "loose search", meaning that if "html" returns no or only few (less than, say, 10) matches it adds "html" and similar to the list.

**The real question now is: How do I do that?**
Does this 'loose searching' has a technical term?

Comment: I don't know how to help in MySQL, but typically called "Fuzzy Matching"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely part of text retrieval and is also called fuzzy matching or approximate string matching.  For instance, go to Google, type "MSYQL" and it will recommend "MYSQL" instead.

Here is a typical approach.  Start with a list of all valid keywords.  Yes, that is the place to begin.  In many text applications, this would be called a lexicon.

The look for your search term(s) in the list of valid keywords.  If you do not find any, then use something called "Levenshtein distance" (described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)) to find the closest matches.  Then use these in your search.  If you search for "Levenshtein distance mysql", you will find implementations of the algorithm here.

If you have just a few known misspellings, then you can also solve the problem with a thesaurus.  This replaces one search term with other terms that might match.